# A terminology question: formally finite ??

Tags: terminology, ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a name for a local homomorphism $\varphi:A\longrightarrow B$ of local rings $A$ and $B$, whose completion $\hat{\varphi}:\hat{A}\longrightarrow\hat{B}$ is a finite homomorphism? (that is, $\hat{B}$ is a module finite extension of $\hat{A}$ via $\hat{\varphi}$). Perhaps *formally finite*?

**EDIT**: Assume $A$ and $B$ are Noetherian.

Comment: I figured I'd tag as algebraic geometry since there is probably a nice geometric way to understand such maps and they may have a term for them. I've never come across anything with this description personally, but I'm not an algebraic geometer

Comment: Actually, there is a notion of a formally finite map: A map between two adic rings $(A,\mathfrak{a}) \to (B,\mathfrak{b})$ is called formally finite if $B/\mathfrak{b}$ is a finite $A$-module.

Comment: May be *analytically finite*? Google does not show any thing like that though. 

Comment: I'll be happy to use *analytically finite*, if there is no name for this.

Comment: @David: For example, if $R$ is a Noetherian local ring of characteristic $p>0$ and its residue field $k$ satisfies $[k:k^p]<\infty$, then the Frobenius endomorphism $\varphi:R\rightarrow R$ may not be a finite map, but $\hat{\varphi}:\hat{R}\rightarrow\hat{R}$ will be a finite map.

Comment: I just found out that in SGA 1 (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203) Grothendieck calls such maps *quasi-finite* (see pages 1 and 2 of SGA 1).

Comment: @Mahdi, why don't you make your last comment an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In SGA 1 ([arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203)) Grothendieck calls such maps quasi-finite (see pages 1 and 2 of SGA 1).

Comment: Right, but now quasifinite morphisms are assumed of finite type (see footnote at the same place in SGA1). For instance, $A\to\hat{A}$ is not quasifinite in general.